# Controller redirect not working in craft 3

Tags: craft3, php, controller

I am working with Craft 3 and in my controller, I am trying to do this

`$this->redirect('https://foobar.test');`

But it is throwing me back to the root url of my craft site. I am confused, what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to add the return keyword :(

`return $this->redirect('https://foobar.test');`